# How to apply jQuery function to DOM elements with similar IDs?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I got this script:

```
<script>
   $('#zoom_01').elevateZoom({});
</script>
```

Where `#zoom_01` is an ID of an image. I have many images with ID's like so:

```
zoom_01
zoom_02
zoom_03
zoom_04
and so on
```

How do i make so that javascript would take all ID's instead of one?
I was thinking something like this:

```
<script>
   <?php 
     foreach ($ArrayAllOfIDs as $i) {  
         $('#<?php echo $i; } ?>').elevateZoom({});
     }
   ?>
</script>
```

But it didnt work.

Comment: You have a typo - should be `$('#<?php echo $i;  ?>').elevateZoom({});`

Comment: You could also iterate through the ids in js. It is possible to have a selector using a string concatenated with a variable.

Comment: The bracket } is at the wrong place. Is it solving the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to all the images that would be affected at the same time.
Ids are used to identify a unique, non repeating item.    Since your images are all pretty much the same, a class can group them together.

Then, change your javascript to select the class.

```
$('.zoom').elevateZoom({});
```

Answer (score 4):

Although using the `class` attribute as mentioned above is probably your best bet, if you are forced to work with the IDs for whatever reason You can use a "starts with" selector like

```
$("[id^=zoom_]").elevateZoom({})
```

which will apply `elevateZoom` to all DOM elements with an `id` that starts with "zoom_".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `elevateZoom` is, but you can likely have this syntax:

```
$('#zoom_01, #zoom_02, #zoom_03, ...').elevateZoom({});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the PHP write out the Javascript so it is available when the page is loaded in the browser.

```
<script>
<?php 
foreach ($ArrayAllOfIDs as $i) {  
    echo '$(\'#zoom_'. $i .'} \').elevateZoom({});\n';
} 
?>
</script>
```